# How to select several checkboxes when use form:checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, spring-form

I use following code to render checkboxes:

```
<form:checkboxes items="${adminRoles}" path="adminRoles"/>
```

I see all the checkboxes rendered but all are unselected.  I need to select several checkboxes according to the model state.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the value of checkbox is refering to a boolean property in your model then you just need to initialize it with default value to true

```
public class User {
     private boolean adminRoles =Boolean.TRUE; //default to checked
...
...
}
```